# Nasm entry and exit code of routines

Tags: nasm, exit, subroutine, entry-point

Is there any way to generate the following header and footer for  routines in nasm without the need to explicitly code them every time I define a new routine?

Header:

```
  push  ebp
  mov   ebp, esp    ; Entry code - set up ebp and esp
```

body of the routine

Footer:

```
  mov   esp, ebp    ; Function exit code
  pop   ebp
  ret
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
some command that generates entry code
body of the routine
some command that generates exit code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a multi-line macro...

```
%macro  prologue 1 

        push    ebp 
        mov     ebp,esp 
        sub     esp,%1 

%endmacro
```

[Source](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.3).

You could define one for function entry and exit.

```
%macro  prologue 1 

        push    ebp 
        mov     ebp,esp 
        sub     esp,%1 

%endmacro

%macro  epilogue 1 

        mov     esp,ebp
        pop     ebp 
        ret

%endmacro
```

The argument supplied is how much room you'd like to reserve on the stack.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Didn't know about them. Thanks for adding that.